# Anchor around div makes it clickable outside of the div itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Programming beginner here, and I'm having a lot of trouble solving this issue with the anchor being clickable outside of my div.

The div has a sliding tab that comes in from the right with a randomly generated film, and the whole tab should be clickable to be redirected to the film's imdb page.
   I have read about it and tried the solution of making the div "display: table-caption", which does fix that, but brings up a myriad of other issues where I have to integrate a margin on the left (it glues the div to the very left otherwise), which works for my specific screen but gets completely offcenter with the smallest of screen/zoom changes.

Is there a more elegant solution to doing so? I just couldn't get the positioning right at all when making the div's display be "table-caption", and nothing else worked.

HTML for the div:

```
<a id="filmAnchor" target="_blank">
<div id="replyDiv" class="blood">
<div id="newreplyDiv">
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

Thank you in advance for any help provided! Here's the codepen for the project:

http://codepen.io/ankee/pen/qqOJXa

Comment: Why not put the anchor inside the div, and make it 100% size etc.

Comment: I just tried your CodePen and it works as you wanted. The tab slides in (the initial "pick a film" slides in from the top left instead of the right) and the whole thing was clickable to the movie's IMDB page.

Comment: @adeneo : I tried doing that, but it still makes the space to the left and the right clickable :/ Did I mess it up somehow?

Comment: @DaveCripps : The animation works as I'd like, the issue is the space to the left and the right of the tab being clickable to go to the IMDB page :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
    #filmAnchor {
     max-width: 1000px;
     display:block;
     margin:auto;
    }
    #newreplyDiv {
     //remove width:1000px;
    }
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! I'm not exactly sure I understand why it does though, how does turning the anchor into a block change it?

Comment: I used the `display:block` so I can add width to your anchor.